# How to avoid whitespace after a tag (link) in Hamlet templates?

Tags: haskell, yesod, hamlet

I cannot find a way to render a link and then comma or full stop right after
it, without whitespace between the link and punctuation. Here is my initial
attempt:

```
<p>
  You can find more information #
  <a href="@{SomeRouteR}">here
  \.
```

or

```
<p>
  You can find more information #
  <a href="@{SomeRouteR}">here
  .
```

This inserts space between the word “here” and “.”.

Another option is:

```
<p>
  You can find more information #
  <a href="@{SomeRouteR}">here</a>.
```

This looks like a win, but HTML is malformed:

```
<p>You can find more information <a href="…">here</a>.</a></p>
```

Is there a way to avoid whitespace between the link and punctuation/other
element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some options:

1. Add `$newline never` to the top of your file, to change the default of adding newlines after tags.
2. Add a `#` immediately following the word `here` to disable the automatic newline for just that tag.
3. Use the explicit end tag like you tried to. But to make this work, you need to start the line with a backslash to tell Hamlet not to autoclose the tag for you: `\<a href=#>here</a>.`

Comment: This is the best framework! Congrats to all people that developed Yesod!

Answer (score 0):

My preferred solution is to add `$newline text` to the top of the file. For example:

```html
$newline text
A line of text.
Another line that ends in
<em>
  emphasized text
.
```

This makes sure that a newline is inserted between the two lines (resulting in a space when rendered in the browser), but no newline/space is inserted after the `<em>` tag.